# TSQL: Tune Dynamic Query Search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In reading on tuning `TSQL` queries, I've seen advice on avoiding (or being careful) about functions in the `WHERE` clause.  However, in some cases - like searches that require dynamic dates from today's date - I'm curious if a query can be tuned further?  For instance, the query below this uses the `DATEADD` function for the current date, which allows the user at anytime to get the correct information for the past thirty days:

```
SELECT *
FROM Zoo..Transportation
WHERE ArrivalDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-30,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

If I try to eliminate the function, `DATEADD`, I could declare a variable that will pull that time and then query the data with that set value stored in the variable, such as:

```
DECLARE @begin DATE
SET @begin = DATEADD(DD,-30,GETDATE())

SELECT *
FROM Zoo..Transportation
WHERE ArrivalDate BETWEEN @begin AND GETDATE()
```

However, the Execution Plan and Statistics show the exact same number of reads, scans and batch costs.

In these instances of dynamic data (for instance, using today's date as a starting point), how do we reduce or eliminate the use of functions in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: What happens to the execution plan when you change the second query so that it is not using GETDATE() in the BETWEEN clause? Instead, try a variable for that as well.

Comment: @Michael that shouldn't matter. SQL Server is smart enough to treat that as a constant.

Comment: @MichaelHarmon - I tested that, and it generates the same result like Aaron mentioned.

Comment: O.K., thanks. Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in the where clause mean doing silly things like:

```
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, ArrivalDate) = 1
```

Or

```
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10), ArrivalDate, 101) = '01/01/2012'
```

E.g. functions against *columns* in the where clause, which in most case destroy sargability (in other words, render an index seek useless and force an index or table scan).

There is one exception that I know of:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ArrivalDate) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

But I would not rely on this for any other scenario.

Comment: So, for instance, an index scan (in this case) would mean that we've optimized as far as we can go related to sargability (or index use)?

Comment: No, you typically will want an index *seek* - a scan generally means it has to read the entire index, which is what you want to avoid. Now, if it turns out that your where clause happens to actually return most of the table, a scan is probably the most efficient way to do it. But just seeing a scan and wiping your hands and thinking you're done optimizing is the wrong way to think about it. It may be true in some cases but every situation is different.

Comment: So, in this case, both queries returned 1000+ rows of data out of 90,000+ rows.  To keep these queries dynamic (and similar date queries like these), how do we code so that SQL Server seeks these data?  I would assume that the second example would tell SQL Server to start at a place, and thus it would only need to *seek* to that place and then look for the data after that location.

Comment: The query you have should seek just fine (it will do a range scan but will seek to the start of the range), but you are probably killing performance by using SELECT * unless you have a covering index that includes all the columns in the table. Do you need all the columns in the output? The question doesn't seem to be about generic index design and I feel like we're going to quickly fall down a bunch of rabbit holes...

Answer (score 1):

IME, using functions within a WHERE clause is only an issue when it operates on data from your query - this means that the function (which itself may be complex SQL) runs for each value in your query - this will likely cause a table scan or similar as the optmiser doesn't know which Index to use (if any).

Your example above is using DATEADD with the current date - the value is probably calculated once (or if it is calculated for each row in your result set, it won't affect the query plan as it doesn't contain data from your query).