# SQL Convert Datetime to varchar10 and subtract 1 day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the query below that I've put together and it runs awful (as I'm sure you can see).

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the way I'm converting date time so that I can reference yesterday's data.

dtInteractionLocalStartTime is a datetime field and I would like it displayed as mm/dd/yyyy instead of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss

Any ideas on how to optimize this? I've spent the past 2 days and I can't figure it out.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
       Date ,
       CONVERT(varchar, VDN) AS VDN ,
       COUNT(*) AS Calls ,
       Avaya
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
              CONVERT(varchar,dtInteractionLocalStartTime,101) AS Date ,
              vcVectorNumber AS VDN ,
              iCompoundID ,
              'CM03' AS Avaya
       FROM NICEHUB3ADTM.nice_dw.dbo.vwNiceDBKitInteraction AS i
       WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10) , dtInteractionLocalStartTime,101) = CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE()-1,101)
         AND iMediaTypesId = 2
         AND tiCallDirectionTypeID = 1
         AND tiInteractionTypeID = 2
         AND iInteractionOpenReasonID & 16 = 0
         AND iInteractionOpenReasonID & 4 = 0
         AND iInteractionID NOT IN ( SELECT iInteractionID
                                     FROM NICEHUB3ADTM.nice_dw.dbo.vwException AS e
                                     WHERE i.iInteractionID = iInteractionID
                                       AND iExceptionTypeID IN (37, 12, 12310)
                                   )
     ) AS derivedtbl_1
GROUP BY Date ,
         CONVERT(varchar,VDN) ,
         Avaya
ORDER BY Date ,
         VDN
```

Comment: `DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT`? Really?

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is the date instead of the datetime, simply use:

```
CAST(yourDate AS DATE)
```

Any formatting done should almost certaintly be done outside of sql, both because sql is not nearly optimized for that kind of thing, and ends up being quite a breach of seperation of concerns when your view logic works your way into the model.

At the very least, change your convert calls in your subqueries to the cast above, and add only a single convert to the outermost select (after the group by). I would still avoid it altogether if you have any ability to refactor the logic elsewhere at the moment.

Comment: +1. This. 100%. Stop converting dates to strings and [especially stop doing it without declaring length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: Good advice, but won't casting to `date` instead of `varchar` still obfuscate any index on that column?  Seems like he could check that `yourDate BETWEEN @startOfYesterday AND @endOfYesterday` to get the same results but potentially avoid a scan... (please correct me if this is wrong).

Comment: @Michael [Oh not BETWEEN, please](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx). Also casting the column as a `DATE` can still use a seek (this is a little-known optimization in SQL Server 2008 that may or may not be wise to rely on). I'm not sure you can avoid a scan in the above query (look at all the filters!) or that an index on that column on its own would be of any value in this case anyway.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Interesting, I wasn't aware that SQL would still seek on a column cast to `DATE`... thanks for enlightening.

Comment: @Michael just FYI (not that I expect you to have my posting history in your cranium, but) I've talked about this before, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15814619/61305).

Comment: @Nicholas Carey 
Thanks for the re-write and "It's a strong indication that you are either asking a wrong or incorrect question, or that you don't understand" you could have cut it off at understand. I can sling some SQL but it's never pretty, I do what I can.
This little diddy that you did
`count(distinct i.iCompoundId)  '
I didn't know you could do that and I have wanted a clean way to do that for a long time. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand and everyone else. I didn't put the top 100 percent in there, I know better than that, SQL management studio keeps putting it in and it makes me angry, SQL Management studio added lots more stuff as well that make me look worse than I am. I think it tries to help

Comment: @Nicholas Carey 

I don't quite follow what you are doing with the date, could you enlighten me a touch more here? Best way might be for me to see a simple change, how would I make it look at the day before yesterday?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson More info in the cast to date trick here: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Answer (score 4):

Some thoughts (as "runs awful" isn't a very good problem statement):

- Get rid of the `top 100 percent`, across the board. That says to return everything, which is what SQL does by default.
- The use of `select distinct` is a **code smell**. It's a strong indication that you are either asking a wrong or incorrect question, or that you don't understand the cardinality of the relationships between the entities involved in the query. SQL deals with *sets*. Sets, by definition, are unique, so if you have to force uniqueness, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.
- Your derived table isn't necessary
- You're doing two bit-twiddling tests against the same column. The can be combined.
- You're doing a correlated subquery and using `not in (...)` rather than `not exists (...)`
- You are converting vcVectorNumber to a varchar. Not knowing its datatype, that seems extraneous: let the application deal with conversion to string.
- In converting the `datetime` column whilst comparing it. That turns it into an expression and the expression can't use indices, so you prevent the query optimizer from making use of any suitable indices. Don't do that. Test `datetime` columns in a way that doesn't require that sort of jumping about, if at all possible: `between` is your friend.

This is how I would refactor your query. I believe this will give the same results:

```
select convert(date,i.dtInteractionLocalStartTime) as Date  ,
       i.vcVectorNumber                            as VDN   ,
       count(distinct i.iCompoundId)               as Calls ,
       'CM03'                                      as Avaya
from NICEHUB3ADTM.nice_dw.dbo.vwNiceDBKitInteraction i
where i.dtInteractionLocalStartTime between dateadd(day ,-1 ,convert(datetime,convert(date,getdate()))) -- yesterday, midnight/start-of-day
                                        and dateadd(ms  ,-3 ,convert(datetime,convert(date,getdate()))) -- yesterday, end-of-day
  and i.iMediaTypesId                     = 2
  and i.tiCallDirectionTypeID             = 1
  and i.tiInteractionTypeID               = 2
  and i.iInteractionOpenReasonId & 0x0014 = 0 -- ( 16|4 is 20, 0x0014)
  and not exists ( select *
                   from NICEHUB3ADTM.nice_dw.dbo.vwException e
                   where e.iInteractionID = i.iInteractionID
                     and e.iExceptionTypeID IN ( 37 , 12 , 12310 )
                 )
group by convert(date,i.dtInteractionLocalStartTime) ,
         i.vcVectorNumber
order by convert(date,i.dtInteractionLocalStartTime) ,
         i.vcVectorNumber
```

One last observation: the 4-part tables names indicate the possible use of a cross-server query or linked server. If so (and in my experience), that can be an expensive operation. Sucking the remote data into local temp tables first can help with performance.

Comment: I agree with most everything else, but I have to correct you: `BETWEEN` is absolutely ***NOT*** your friend. I would say he is [the furthest thing from a friend you have](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx). Your fun little `subtract 3 milliseconds` trick falls completely on its face if the underlying data type changes to, say, `SMALLDATETIME` or - to a lesser extent - `DATETIME2`.

Comment: Whatever. It's not an argument I'm going to engage in. Thank's for the comment. Anybody who changes datatypes in a database or computer program and doesn't inspect their codebase for potential problems and remediate them, especially when the change widens or narrows the domain of the variable or alters its precision, is by any standard failing in their due diligence. That is all.

Comment: If you use a proper, open-ended range (e.g. `>= StartDate and < EndDate + 1` then there is no need to worry about whether inspecting the entire codebase (or even knowing that anyone has done this -3ms trick anywhere) is practical or even possible. The person who changes the database isn't always the person who changes the app code, and sometimes they can't even access it, and sometimes it's not possible to change because bad SQL is embedded in a compiled app with no source code. I hate to say it but quite frankly the convert to varchar is actually safer than BETWEEN.

Comment: ...meaning, I'd rather have accurate data in 3 seconds than potentially wrong data in 2.

Comment: Guys guys, no need to quibble, you are both smarter than me on this stuff!
Nicholas, Thanks for the re-write and "It's a strong indication that you are either asking a wrong or incorrect question, or that you don't understand" you could have cut it off at understand. I can sling some SQL but it's never pretty, I do what I can.
This little diddy that you did
`count(distinct i.iCompoundId)  '
I didn't know you could do that and I have wanted a clean way to do that for a long time. Thank you thank you thank you!

Aaron,